# Advanced search in matrix to find the rows that have special characteristics

Tags: matlab

I need to find the rows that have:

**a)** the sum of all elements in the row = 6

**b)** two consecutive elements in the row = 1 and the other three consecutive elements in the row = 0

For example,

 Given the following matrix:-

```
X=[ 0  0  1  0  1  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0;
    1  1  1  0  1  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0; 
    0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  1  1; 
    1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0;
    0  0  1  0  1  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0]
```

The mentioned characteristics are in the row 1 and 5 only 
so I want to get these rows as an answer.

Comment: Are there only `1` and `0` in the matrix? Must the sum be exactly `=6`? And would  `0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1` satisfy the conditions?

Comment: Does `0 0 0 1 1` satisfy the second codition? How about `1 1 0 1 0 0 0`?

Comment: About the first comment it satisfied the first condition but not accept with second constraints because I need in the new matrix the rows that have those two constraints

Comment: About the second comment only 1 1 0 0 0 or 0 0 0 1 1 satisfied the second constraints so 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 is not acceptable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate matrix have special charactristics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39486469/generate-matrix-have-special-charactristics)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
X=[ 0  0  1  0  1  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0;
    1  1  1  0  1  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0; 
    0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  1  1; 
    1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  0;
    0  0  1  0  1  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0];

sum6rows=find(sum(X,2)==6);   %finding the row numbers that meet condition-1
if sum6rows
req=X(sum6rows,:); %storing the rows in a variable which meet condition-1 
%now finding the row numbers that also meet condition-2
test=mat2str(req) ; % Converting the matrix into a string
j=unique(ceil(findstr([test(2:end-1)], '1 1 0 0 0')/(2*(size(X,2))))); %finding our pattern in the string
req=req(j.',:); % removing those rows which don't meet condition-2
end
```